# NOT WORKING domain.com/cv WORK domain.com/cv/ www.bluetrendy.com/cv www.bluetrendy.com/cv/ any ideas?

Tags: heroku, godaddy-api

`DON'T WORK
bluetrendy.com/cv

WORK
bluetrendy.com/cv/
[www.bluetrendy.com/cv](http://www.bluetrendy.com/cv)
[www.bluetrendy.com/cv/`](http://www.bluetrendy.com/cv/%60)

my node js server file is attached here

https://bitbucket.org/unutoiul/bluetrendy.com/src/development/server/app.js

also, the Godaddy CNAME is forward is:

CNAME www floral-parasaurolophus-a91syo4zyfuuk9w6ys95jjga.herokudns.com

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/6sKVN.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6sKVN.png)

and my forward GoDaddy is

I need help, why doesn't work...

I tried everything for 3 days ...

NOT WORKING domain.com/cv  WORK  domain.com/cv/ [www.bluetrendy.com/cv](http://www.bluetrendy.com/cv) [www.bluetrendy.com/cv/](http://www.bluetrendy.com/cv/)  any ideas?